# I Want To Confirm That My Bitcoins Are Being Held In New Wallet

Tags: transaction-verification, trezor

I sent a couple bitcoin from one of my trezor wallets to a different trezor wallet.

I don't know the details about how bitcoin "sending" between wallets work, and now I feel the need to confirm that it all went smoothly. Essentially, I'd like to see confirmation that all my bitcoin transfered to to my new wallet.

the receiving address of the new wallet, (the one thats supposed to be holding the bitcoin now), is: 1HyETxKBZshfu2cdjEWMYntDFabFXsrHe2

Can someone help me out here? How do I check to see if everything went over to the new wallet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check on 3rd-party pages whether they have knowledge of your transaction: E.g. [Blockexplorer](https://blockexplorer.com) shows that address [1HyETxKBZshfu2cdjEWMYntDFabFXsrHe2](https://blockexplorer.com/address/1HyETxKBZshfu2cdjEWMYntDFabFXsrHe2) received just short of 35 BTC last week. If that's the amount you sent, you were successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [blockchain](https://blockchain.info/) itself and see if the transaction has succeded and the amount in your wallet.

Comment: Nit: blockchain.info is a company, not "the blockchain itself". Also, your answer is essentially the same as mine. ;)

Comment: @Murch Of course, but it shows blockchain info. If you want to check the real blockchain you will need something like `bitcoin-qt` or any client that downloads the block chain and lets you query it.